# How to make Logitech M510 work in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mouse

What Logitech software and additional drivers allow my Logitech M510 mouse to work on Linux Ubuntu 20.04? if so, which additional drivers are required?

I want all 7 programmable mouse buttons to work on my linux laptop (HP Pavilion g series)

Answer (score 0):

Try [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/). It does not mention the M510 as supported explicitly, but you may get lucky and it works.

Otherwise you may have some luck using [xbindkeys](https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/), although it is more work to set up.